# rsync does't work

Tags: ssh, rsync

I set up a new ec2 ubuntu server and I'm unable to use rsync to push a file up.  I can ssh to the machine with my keypair.  I'm not sure why this looks like it works but finishes in half a second and there is nothing in /home/ubuntu on the server.

```
➜  ~  rsync -av -i ~/.ec2/my-keypair ~/Downloads/pushcom.2012-06-26T01-10-04.gz  ubuntu@stage.push.com
building file list ... done
>f..t.... gsg-keypair
>f..t.... pushwoodcom.2012-06-26T01-10-04.gz

sent 3624 bytes  received 64 bytes  7376.00 bytes/sec
total size is 3392  speedup is 0.92
```

I've tried 50 different ways of the rsync command but I can't get anything to work.  Please help!  Thanks

Comment: Don't you need to specify the directory for "ubuntu@stage.push.com"?  Something like `ubuntu@stage.push.com:/path/to/destination/`.

Comment: Yes, destination directory is mandatory when pushing files. It's only optional when pulling.

Comment: There is a destination directory -- `ubuntu@stage.push.com`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That's not a directory. That's the username and server. The colon is required to delineate a directory.

Comment: @Adrian: That's a path -- `ubuntu@stage.push.com` is a perfectly legal directory or file name. A colon is only required to specify both a server and a path (including an empty path). Only one thing is being specified here, so no colon is necessary.

Comment: You can be as pedantic as you want, but my solution gets the user what they actually want and yours doesn't.

Comment: @Adrian: I don't see where either of us offered a solution. I'm just pointing out that in the OP's command `ubuntu@stage.push.com` is the destination path, and it's a perfectly legal and valid one. And a colon is *not* required to delineate a directory unless a server is being specified. (Which it's not, in the OP's command.)

Comment: Of course he's not specifying a server, because there's no colon in there just like I mentioned before.

Comment: I've used `ubuntu@stage.push.com` to upload files into `/home/ubuntu` before.  I just cant figure out why it's not working.  I can ssh to the machine just fine.

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
rsync -av -e "ssh -i ~/.ec2/my-keypair" ~/Downloads/pushcom.2012-06-26T01-10-04.gz  ubuntu@stage.push.com:/home/ubuntu/
```

rsync has different syntax then ssh. Or you may use "scp" which has simmilar syntax as ssh (except with -p/-P for ports)